# What is the default behaviour, if no ciphers are enabled

Tags: encryption, tls

Lets assume for example, that a server is configured to use TLS 1.0 and there are no ciphers enabled for it. 
What will be the default behaviour if a client connects to it?
Will the server use any null ciphers by default to complete the TLS handshake?

Comment: I'm opposing the on-going off-topic close vote. This question is asking what a server does / should do when no ciphers are configured. This is very easily answerable using the protocol specification and questions about cryptographic protocols (like TLS) themselves are on-topic. And beyond, if you _really_ wanted to close it, it much rather belongs on SF because it's a question about server configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will server use any null ciphers by default to complete the ssl
> handshake.

No. The TLS v1.0 specification *explicitely* states that the `TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` cipher suite must not be negotiated. However, using a cipher suite that only offers authentication but no encryption is valid (and done in e.g. Windows Update). An example for such a suite is `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA`.

To quote appendix A.5 of [RFC2246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246):

> `TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` is specified and is the initial state of a
> TLS connection during the first handshake on that channel, but must
> not be negotiated, as it provides no more protection than an
> unsecured connection.

$\space$

> Lets for example, a server is configured to use TLS1.0 and there is no
> ciphers enabled for it, what will be the default behaviour if a client
> connects to it.

It depends, either the server implementation will override your configuration and use the default list of accepted cipher suites, or it will refuse all incoming TLS connections because no client can offer an accepted cipher suite to the server (because it doesn't accept any).